# Whenever I am going to create or Build an authenticated experience page on community cloud , I am getting below error...(Profile-SystemAdministrator)

Tags: experience-cloud, community-cloud

[image]

It will allow me as a system admin to create or build an **unauthenticated** experience page or app....but is doesn't allow me to create authenticated experience page...

Comment: are you creating community in scratch org or scratch org shape?

Comment: i have not created any scratch org or scratch org shape...